# gnuplot: getting wrong columnheader?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using GNUPLOT 4.6 on Linux, with this code:

```
set datafile separator ","  
set style data linespoint  
set xdata time;set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M";set autoscale  
plot 'PHY_Long_CHA_CMPK.csv' every ::7 using 2:3 title columnheader(3),\
     'PHY_Long_CHA_CMPK.csv' every ::7 using 2:4 title columnheader(4),\
     'PHY_Long_CHA_CMPK.csv' every ::7 using 2:5 title columnheader(5),\  
pause -1
```

And I'm not getting the correct columnheader,(First, Second, Third), just filename.csv all the time. 
Can anybody help me please? 
I shouldn't change the data of file filename.csv. So I'm trying with GNUPLOT functions...

Example of filename.csv:

```
filename.csv  
Serial number  
From : 2015/12/09 13:15  
To   : 2016/06/09 23:30  
sampling rate : 15  

No.,"time","First","Second","Third"  
1,"2015/12/09 13:30",0,0,0  
2,"2015/12/09 13:45",0,0,0  
3,"2015/12/09 14:00",0,0,0  
4,"2015/12/09 14:15",0,0,0
```

Answer (score 2):

Because now, all the column header is "filename.csv" ;-) you have to comment-out the comment lines...

```
#filename.csv  
#Serial number  
#From : 2015/12/09 13:15  
#To   : 2016/06/09 23:30  
#sampling rate : 15
#
No.,"time","First","Second","Third"  
1,"2015/12/09 13:30",0,0,0  
2,"2015/12/09 13:45",0,0,0  
3,"2015/12/09 14:00",0,0,0  
4,"2015/12/09 14:15",0,0,0
```

---

And should not to use '**,\**' at the last plotting line.

Comment: +1 You beat me while I was writing my answer. I will leave it because there is a further misunderstanding in the OP regarding how `every` works and because I propose an `awk` alternative that works also if the OP cannot edit the file (for whatever reason).

Comment: @Miguel you're right: I hadn't think about why the OP use `every` :)

Answer (score 2):

Your column header is actually `filename.csv` because that's the first line in your file. The `every ::7` is not doing what you expect it to do, that is, skip the first 7 lines. What it does is skip the first 7 *data entries*. If you want to skip the header, you can use comment symbols `#` or pipe the input removing the first few lines with `awk`:

```
set datafile separator ","  
set style data linespoint  
set xdata time;set timefmt "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M";set autoscale  
plot "< awk '(NR > 6){print $0}' PHY_Long_CHA_CMPK.csv" using 2:3 title columnheader(3),\
     "< awk '(NR > 6){print $0}' PHY_Long_CHA_CMPK.csv" using 2:4 title columnheader(4),\
     "< awk '(NR > 6){print $0}' PHY_Long_CHA_CMPK.csv" using 2:5 title columnheader(5)
pause -1
```

Comment: I would `awk 'NR>6'`